# Key reference and table reference don't match

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a foreign key, but I am getting this error. I don't understand why. 
The query is:

[click here to see the screenshot of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Jwd.png)

Comment: Did you read about adding a foreign key constraint from docs?

Comment: MySQL foreign key definitions do not automatically match up field names, they must be specified. Also, you're better off using something like auto_increment int "dept_id" field to make a "surrogate" key, and then referencing that. Otherwise, name changes will have to be managed across references, and indexing/comparison/joining (pretty much anything) is more expensive with "string" values than integer ones. _Heck, even if you're using a small character encoding, a 5 character string takes up more space than a 9-digit number._

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have given a wrong reference. You need to reference the primary key of another table, not just the table. See this example-

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
id INT, 
parent_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```